# How to load React components inside a container app via AJAX

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, microservices

What are the best practices associated with loading/inserting React components in an existing React application via AJAX.

I am considering having a "container app" that loads various React components via AJAX. How could this be done?

How can this work with webpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack has `require.ensure` which lets you load modules async. This can improve performance if you have a lot of rarely used modules. For react components, you can use [`react-proxy-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/react-proxy-loader) to cut down on boilerplate.

I have a fork of it that works with es6 modules.

```
npm install 'brigand/react-proxy-loader#use-exports-default'
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how you would use with `require.ensure` or `react-proxy` or `react-proxy-loader` inside of a `fetch` request's `.then` method?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah you import the component with react-proxy-loader and then when you render it for the first time it loads.